# T-SQL: How do I find out where a FK is pointing?

Tags: database, t-sql, foreign-keys

I've got a query which returns me the name of a column

```
SELECT name 
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('tblu_utenti_00') AND name LIKE '%ling%'
```

For that column I would like to know if it has got a FK and which table the FK is pointing to.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the catalog views to get that information - this is the "general purpose" query that shows all defined foreign key relationships and what tables/columns they refer to:

```
SELECT
    ForeignKeyName = fk.name,
    ParentTableName = parent.name,
    ParentColumnName = parcol.name,
    ReferencedTableName = referenced.Name,
    ReferencedColumnName = refcol.name
FROM 
    sys.foreign_keys fk
INNER JOIN 
    sys.foreign_key_columns fkc ON fk.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables parent ON parent.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables referenced ON referenced.object_id = fk.referenced_object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns parcol ON fkc.parent_object_id = parcol.object_id AND fkc.parent_column_id = parcol.column_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns refcol ON fkc.referenced_object_id = refcol.object_id AND fkc.referenced_column_id = refcol.column_id
```

You can now join this to your `sys.columns` query and check if that column is used as the "parent column" or the "referenced column" in any foreign key constraint.

```
.....
WHERE
    (parent.Name = 'tblu_utenti_00' AND parcol.Name LIKE '%ling%')
    OR
    (referenced.Name = 'tblu_utenti_00' AND refcol.Name LIKE '%ling%')
```